# What is .net 3.5 sp1?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

(1) What is service pack ?

(2) I want to work   with mvc. So I have installed visual studio 2008 then I tried to install mvc 1.0 but there is error that you have to install 3.5 sp1.Then is it necessary to install 3.5 sp1 or 3.5 .net framework is installed automatically when I installed vs 2008 ?

(3) I tried to download 3.5 sp1 but it is of 2.8 MB, now if I install it then, will I able to install mvc 1.0 ?

Comment: Sorry but why should it be closed because I don't know what is service pack and I am not able to install mvc and work with it ?

Comment: 1. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Service_pack Next look at system requirements [here](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=53289097-73ce-43bf-b6a6-35e00103cb4b&displaylang=en#Requirements)

Comment: No, but because you are not looking up on google what a service pack is.

Comment: @TomTom, At first time when I was facing this problem, I got stackoverflow first in my mind. So I did not search it in google.And I know that I can get better answer and if there is some other problem then also it can be solved here so..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you need to install the service pack. Yes, 3.5 was installed with .NET 2008 but MVC 1 was released after VS2008 and needs the updates. Yes, if you install the service pack you should be able to install MVC 1.

It sounds like you already have the bootstrap installer for the service pack, but if not you can get it from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/netframework/cc378097.aspx

However you should really start with ASP.MVC 2 instead - there's some nice new features.

Comment: @Rup, I downloaded 3.5 sp1 but it is of only 2.8 MB, so that is right set up ? And if I use MVC 2 then will I have to download other sp ?

Comment: @Harikrishna IIRC the 2.8MB thing is only the installer which will then download the service pack, which is bigger in size

Comment: @Rup, then I can not download the sp1 directly then I intall it ?

Comment: Yes, as dkson says that's be the bootstrap installer which will download extra bits as required to update your system. There's a link to the all-in-one installer on that page too. I don't know if that SP will upgrade a .NET 2 install all the way but I can't see why not. Why don't you want to just try it?

Comment: Here's the link to the full package installer from that page: http://download.microsoft.com/download/2/0/e/20e90413-712f-438c-988e-fdaa79a8ac3d/dotnetfx35.exe

Comment: ok. But if I install 2010 then all this thing will be required like, install sp1 and all these ?

Comment: VS2010? That uses .NET 4 which is a separate runtime. If you want to develop code targeting .NET 3.5 with MVC 1 then yes. If you only want to target .NET 4 then no.

Comment: @Rup, Ultimately I want to use mvc, any how..

Comment: Then I'd recommend you stick to the latest stuff: install VS2010, which includes MVC 2 as part of the install.

Comment: @Rup, If I download express 2010 then will it involve mvc, because you said that if I use 2010 then it is good because it involves more features with mvc.

Comment: I don't know about the 2010 express, sorry, but the 2010 professional and premium versions do install MVC 2 and the MVC templates by default. I would think so, though, or if not you can just install MVC 2 on top of it. I'm not 100% sure there's better integration with 2010 than 2008 though.

Comment: @Rup, Can I ask one more question to you, which is not programming related but it is job related ? I want your suggestion.

Comment: Sure, although I'm not really an expert on career stuff - you might do better with http://careeroverflow.com/

Comment: @Rup,Thanks for your support first.. I want to ask that I am fresher and I have recently compeleted my MCA in june-2010. I have got the job. Now If I come there in future, can I got the job there, is there opportunity to get the job ?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure what you're asking: you've been offered a job but you want to defer starting it? You'd have to talk to your employer I guess. In my limited experience small companies are happy to recruit new graduates starting all year around whereas large companies with formal induction programmes prefer you to start on or around a fixed set of start dates to coincide with those. I don't really know sorry!

Comment: @Rup,No.. Not like that. I am doing my job with hard work and my full attention is over there. But after some 2 or 3 years if I want to come in England, is there chance to get the job there in England ?

Comment: I don't know - I can't see why not. My company do interview foreign applicants and whilst we're happy to call abroad for phone interviews we do want to do a face-to-face interview before we hire. So I'm not sure if you could definitely get a job before coming to the UK but it might be possible. There's always people hiring programmers, though, yes - there's plenty of jobs on Stack Overflow's job site for London. if you're not from the EU you would need a work permit but as long as you have academic qualifications are taking a well-paying job there shouldn't be any problem.

Comment: @Rup, Which academic qualifications are required to get the job there ? I have completed my master degree here.. May I have your gmail Id or yahoo id,so we can chat,and I can ask you questions which are in my mind, if possible.

Comment: Here's the table for qualifications: http://www.ukba.homeoffice.gov.uk/workingintheuk/tier1/general/eligibility/pointsassessment/qualifications/ - it looks like under the current scheme if you're under 30 and have a masters you need to find a UK job earning £35,000+.

Comment: @Rup, May I have your gmail or yahoo id, So we can chat, when you are free.

Comment: I don't use gmail. My yahoo id is rmww2 but I don't use Yahoo messenger and I don't have IM in this office.

Comment: @Rup, No.. no problem. I have completed my master degree in computer. Then  for coming there , I have to do any other course or should learn othere technology or anything else

Comment: In immigration terms I don't think you need any more qualifications, no - just what you'd need to get the job!

Answer (score 2):

> The .NET Framework 3.5 SP1 is a full
>   cumulative update that contains many
>   new features.

Have a look [here](http://support.microsoft.com/?scid=kb%3Ben-us%3B951847&x=8&y=11)

Install it, then you can install MVC 1